# Check if two different objects has property

Tags: c#

assuming that we have two class:

```
class A

{
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }

    public int Prop2 { get; set; }


}

class B
{

    public int Prop2 { get; set; }

    public int Prop3 { get; set; }


}
```

what is the best way and how to implement method which would take object of type A or B and check if has Prop2 and return object of type passed as arquemnt, sth like this :

```
 T CheckIfHasProp2<T>(T)
{
}
```

generic, dynamic , interface or sth differnt ? I would take intferace but I don't wanna lose other properties.

Comment: Why does the method need to return the same type? Is it a new instance of that type or the same instance? Perhaps if you explained why you were doing this instead of just what you're doing it would help, because honestly I feel like you're just heading down the wrong path to solve whatever problem it is you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way would be to know the type of your objects :)

To signal an object has an ability to do something in C#, you use an interface.

Interfaces signify a "can do" relationship. They represent a *contract* a piece of code must obey.

If `Prop2` for example is the ability to eat , you can create an `IEat` interface and have classes that can eat inherit from it. In the below example I call the interface `IProp2` - you should give your interfaces meaningful names that describe the actual behavior:

```
interface IProp2
{
    int Prop2 { get; set; }
}
class A : IProp2
{
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }

    public int Prop2 { get; set; }


}

class B : IProp2
{

    public int Prop2 { get; set; }

    public int Prop3 { get; set; }
}
// inside main
var a = new A();
// check if it's a member, though usually you don't need this
Console.WriteLine(a is IProp2);  // true
```

(This is unlike other languages like TypeScript where inheritance is not nominal, but that's another story).

Note that while `dynamic` would work, it works against the type system and it effectively means throwing all the benefits of a statically type checked language away. With interfaces you get a *compile time* error if one of the classes does not implement the interface it inherits.

Comment: I would note that you could use reflection as well, but an interface is a much better (and easier) solution if you know the types ahead of time, which it sounds like you do

Comment: I know that , but the problem is if I use interface type which is poorer as arguemnt for this method I will not be able to recreate my object

Comment: What do you mean by _recreate my object_?

Comment: @kosnkov that's _exactly_ what type safety gives you. If you have an object that is an interface _that is all we know about it_. This is _good_ and is what the type system ensures for us. If you need to use other methods that depend on specific classes - then you need to explicitly say it.'